# Importing data with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing a query log as a table into a data frame with Pandas/Python as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
q_data_1 = pd.read_table('table_data.txt', skiprows=6, thousands=',')
```

I get the following table:

- Col 0 - index
- Col 1 - query strings (e.g. 'news in NY')
- Col 2 - pageviews (e.g. '10,102')
- Col 3 - average duration (e.g. '00:03:06')
- Col 4 - % new visits (e.g. '32.4%')

At the moment the dtype of all of the columns is 'object'. How do I convert the dtype of col 2 to integer, col 3 to time, col 4 to percentage?

Some of the columns that contain values as string may be noisy (i.e. contain actual text strings - although the occurrence of these is low; so every time a coversion above fails I would like to substitute 0 as the appropriate dtype).

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have tried

```
q_data_1.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).dtypes
```

and (with columns[1] being page views)

```
q_data_1[q_data_1.columns[1]] = q_data_1[q_data_1.columns[1]].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

Which gave the error:

```
TypeError: convert_objects() got an unexpected keyword argument 'convert_numeric'
```

Comment: Can not check as I do not have your data. Suggest that you methodically look at your datframe to see whtas going on.  *list(df.columns)* to see what the column names are.  SOmetimes there is a space from the parser left.   ALso check df.values  and then slice into it to see what the types are with in that.   the pd.read_csv method has a huge number of options that can probably solve most or all of possible formatting,   you just have to dig.   Read http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the [convert_objects](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/basics.html#object-conversion)  and [astype](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/basics.html#astype) methods.

So assuming your dataframe is called `df` and you wanted to first ensure that all data in column 2 is numeric, you would call:

```
df[df.columns[2]] = df[df.columns[2]].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

While this will attempt to convert the entire column to appropriate numeric values, you may not yet have only integer types.  You could follow this up with:

```
df[df.columns[2]] = df[df.columns[2]].astype('int')
```

I believe you are limited to python and numpy types, so you may have to settle for a `float` for column 4.

Comment: Ryan thanks for the help - I got an error when I tried the first line using convert_objects (have edited my question to reflect)